# Can anybody tell me what the problem here is ? Piglatin

Tags: c#

The Input is `3.3 is a double` and the output I should get `3.3 isway away oubleday` but instead I am getting `.33ay isway away oubleday`.

Does anyone know why ?

```
            Console.WriteLine("Give a sentence: ");
            string sentence = Console.ReadLine();

            string pigLatin = ToPigLatin(sentence);

            Console.WriteLine(pigLatin);

            static string ToPigLatin(string sentence)
            {

                const string vowels = "AEIOUYaeioy";
                List<string> pigWords = new List<string>();

                foreach (string word in sentence.Split(' '))
                {
                    string firstLetter = word.Substring(0, 1);
                    string restOfWord = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
                    int currentLetter = vowels.IndexOf(firstLetter);

                    if (currentLetter == -1)
                    {
                        pigWords.Add(restOfWord + firstLetter + "ay");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pigWords.Add(word + "way");
                    }
                }
                return string.Join(" ", pigWords);
            }
```

Comment: Walk through it with the debugger to see what is happening.

Comment: Consider editing your question and explaining what the function `ToPigLatin()` is supposed to do.

Comment: I don't think this implements pig latin as I understand it (take all initial chars up to the first vowel, rearrange so it's rest+initialchars+"ay"..) But your problem seems to be you don't ignore numbers.. `double.TryParse` the "word" first, and if it parses, skip the "turn it to pig latin" part

Comment: I don't see anything in your code where you reject something like `"3.3"` as a word.  So it gets treated the same as any other word.

Comment: @Cleptus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin.  It's a goofy word encoding that North American kids learn in their elementary school playgrounds.  Perhaps in other places too - I grew up in Canada but have been in the US for decades

Answer (score 0):

Consider ignoring numbers:

```
if(double.TryParse(word, out var _)) 
    pigWords.Add(word);

else if (currentLetter == -1)
    pigWords.Add(restOfWord + firstLetter + "ay");
else
    pigWords.Add(word + "way");
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your approach, IMHO, is that you should translate *words* like `is`, `double`, but keep intact *numbers* like `3.3`, *punctuations* etc. `string.Split(...)` is *not powerful enough*. In order to replace *words* only, we can use a simple *regular expression*:

```
  using System.Text.Regular.Expressions;

  ...

  string result = Regex.Replace(text, "[A-Za-z]+", m => WordToPigLatin(m.Value));
```

here `WordToPigLatin` have only to operate with *proper words* only and that's why much easier to implement:

```
  static string WordToPigLatin(string value) {
    const string vowels = "AEIOUYaeioy";

    if (vowels.Contains(value[0]))
      return value + "way";

    string prefix = string.Concat(value.TakeWhile(c => !vowels.Contains(c)));

    return value.Substring(prefix.Length) + prefix + "ay";
  }
```

Combining it all together

**Code:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Regular.Expressions;

...

private static string ToPigLatin(string text) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    return text;

  static string WordToPigLatin(string value) {
    const string vowels = "AEIOUYaeioy";

    if (vowels.Contains(value[0]))
      return value + "way";

    string prefix = string.Concat(value.TakeWhile(c => !vowels.Contains(c)));

    return value.Substring(prefix.Length) + prefix + "ay";
  }

  return Regex.Replace(text, "[A-Za-z]+", m => WordToPigLatin(m.Value));
}
```

**Demo:**

```
string demo = "3.3 is a double, - not an integer (!) like +1 or -5";

Console.Write(ToPigLatin(demo));
```

**Outcome:**

```
3.3 isway away oubleday, - otnay anway integerway (!) ikelay +1 orway -5
```